# "Give the word": meanings and syntax

Tags: meaning, idioms

The expression “**[give the word](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/give-the-word)**” means to order someone to do something.

> When I give the word, start the machine.

Can it also mean *to permit/allow?*

I also wonder if this is possible:

> He gave me the word to start the machine.

Comment: It is not quite correct to say that 'Give the word means to order someone to do something'. 'Give the word can mean that, but it can also mean 'give a signal that something may be done'. Are you thirsty? Just give me the word and I'll pour you a beer.

Comment: The question isn't bad but I think the two downvotes are from users who want to see askers actually *show* research and effort. At least that's my interpretation, and why I edited the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can in the sense of 'he told me when it was OK to start the machine', but not in the sense of giving a general permission to do it.

https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/give+the+word

Comment: Kate thank you. You forgot to answer if this is correct "He gave me the word to start the machine."

Comment: I thought it was all part of the same question! You can use that sentence with the meaning I stated.